# Search for a particular date in sheet 1 with FROM and TO dates in 2 columns and then paste data from a column in same row in sheet 1 into sheet 2

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am trying to get this formula to work but can't
here is link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PmUqg-G-TEZhTFj_viqy3XY0KSiJJiVVGDcN8VV57uI/edit?usp=sharing

`Array Formula` to `Lookup` Date Between Two Dates:
Master Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(F2:F),(VLOOKUP(F2:F,{row(indirect("A"&A2):indirect("A"&B5)),transpose(split(join("",(rept(C2:C5&"|",(B2:B5-A2:A5)+1))),"|"))},2,FALSE)),))
```

Comment: Make a copy of your spreadsheet without personal data and update your question, to understand it is better that we can look at the case visually!

Comment: I have added the link and put a description of what I am trying to do in cells E2 to E5 on "Calendar 21" sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PmUqg-G-TEZhTFj_viqy3XY0KSiJJiVVGDcN8VV57uI/edit#gid=1640863036

Comment: I have added comments on sheet called JDT Test to show how suggested solution is not looking between the start and and End dates and returning text "FREE" when the selected date in Column F does not appear in the dates in columns A & B ie date 30/1/2021 should return the text "FREE" as the date 30/1/2021 is not within any of the date rages in Columns A & B

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, {A2:A, C2:C}, 2, 1)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks but when you copy formula down you get error as per updated sheet. please look at what I am trying to do on actual sheet called calender 21

Comment: this is arrayformula which autocompletes so no need to put it on each row. see your test sheet cell G2 and notice G3 has no formula

Comment: thanks and I understand now but it does not look between the 2 dates "start date" and "end date" so that if the there is not tour on a date it returns the text FREE".